# Rewrite code from htaccess to nginx config?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I have problem with implement my rewrite code from htaccess file into nginx config.
I've already tried generator : http://winginx.com/htaccess  for generate my rewrite 
code.

**My nginx config code:**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;
        return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;       
}

server {
        listen 80;
        root /usr/share/nginx/www;
        index index.php;
        server_name www.example.com;
        error_page 404 http://www.example.com/404.php;
        autoindex off;
        error_log  /usr/share/nginx/www/nginx_error.log  warn;

   location / {
        rewrite ^([^\.]*)$ /$1.php;
    }

    location = / {
        rewrite ^ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }

}
```

**I wanna implement this from my .htaccess:**

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-/_]+)$ admin/index.php?hotelname=$1&do=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(([A-Za-z0-9-/]+)+)$ admin/index.php?hotelname=$1 [L]
```

**Generated code from tool:**

```
location / {
  rewrite ^/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-/_]+)$ /admin/index.php?hotelname=$1&do=$2;
  rewrite ^/(([A-Za-z0-9-/]+)+)$ /admin/index.php?hotelname=$1 break;
}
```

I have alredy tried implement this last lines of code to my location blocks but not working at all..
I will be very greateful for every opinion!
Regards
Makromat

Comment: Hello @DanFromGermany you can see better described this there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21393803/nginx-rewrite-rule-for-cms-backend Do you have any idea ?

Comment: What were the other lines related to url-rewriting in the original `.htaccess`? any `RewriteBase` for example?

Answer (score 1):

The blind kind of conversion would be

```
rewrite ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-/_]+)$ admin/index.php?hotelname=$1&do=$2&$query_string last;
rewrite ^(([A-Za-z0-9-/]+)+)$ admin/index.php?hotelname=$1 last;
```

But I would prefer if I understand the question more to produce a more optimum rewrite.

When do I know if the URL should be passed to `/admin` or not, give me an actual URI for backend and for frontend.

Comment: My skype is matej.marko7 please invite me thanks! Achive solution will be more easy and finall code will be uploaded.

Comment: Now I have internal server error 500 on each file (css,image) but php is loaded on http://www.domain.com/admin/index.php. But all other is same like before. (When I'm logged in page is redirected to http://www.domain.com/username and in browser is only "File not found." )

Comment: I think this is a bad practice, if I go to `domain.com/abc`, how does the application know if `abc` is a page or a username ?

Comment: email me on `blog [at] abushady [dot] com` so you don't post your domain here

Answer (score 1):

Usually rewrites are better managed in nginx using nginx way of thinking. And this new way of thinking is more based on [`try_file`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files).

So you may try something like that (untested):

```
location ^~ "/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-/_]+)"  {
    try_files $uri admin/index.php?hotelname=$1&do=$2&$args;
}
location ^~ "(([A-Za-z0-9-/]+)+)" {
    try_files $uri /admin/index.php?hotelname=$1;
}
location = / {
    rewrite ^ /index.php;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}
```

If direct access on given `$uri`should never happen, then remove that part from the try_files. Now I'm also unsure of your second regex `(([A-Za-z0-9-/]+)+)`, why not using:

```
location ^~ "/([A-Za-z0-9-/])+"
```

Or

```
location ^~ "/([A-Za-z0-9-])+/"
```

So there's maybe something I do not see, even in your apache rewrites.