# Nginx rewrite rule for cms backend

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I need to make url rewrite rules (server blocks) in nginx server same like in my previous apache server.
This is code from .htaccess what I need to implement (convert) into my existing one:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-/_]+)$ admin/index.php?hotelname=$1&do=$2 [QSA]

RewriteRule ^(([A-Za-z0-9-/]+)+)$ admin/index.php?hotelname=$1 [L]
```

This code is in my website because I need to hide in adress bar folder(/admin/) where is located files after login. And when somebody is already login, adress bar is like **www.domain.com/username** and when you click to menu adress is like **www.domain.com/username/page1**, **www.domain.com/username/page2**, **www.domain.com/username/page3**. 
This is what I need to achive in nginx. Because now is complete backend without function. When I login to backend, I'm redirected to **www.domain.com/username** but on screen I can see only **File not found.** In backend working only when I manualy add **www.domain.com/admin/index.php**.

This is my actual config for nginx :

```
server_names_hash_bucket_size  64;

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        root /usr/share/nginx/www;
        index index.php;
        server_name www.example.com;
        error_page 404 http://www.example.com/404.php;
        autoindex off;



   location / {
        rewrite ^([^\.]*)$ /$1.php;
    }

    location = / {
        rewrite ^ /index.php;
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
      }
}
```

When I try to change my block to:

```
location / {
        rewrite ^([^\.]*)$ /$1.php;
        rewrite ^/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-/_]+)$ /admin/index.php?hotelname=$1&do=$2;
        rewrite ^/(([A-Za-z0-9-/]+)+)$ /admin/index.php?hotelname=$1 break;
    }
```

Each my css file have error 500...

I will be very grateful with any help!
Thanks a lot.

Comment: how can you tell the difference between backend and frontend url's? or are just all backend?

Comment: @ Mohammad AbuShady  frontend is like **www.example.com/frontend-pages** and after login to backend **www.example.com/username** and pages in backend **www.example.com/username/pages-backend**

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady Question is available for bounty there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20018951/rewrite-code-from-htaccess-to-nginx-config

Comment: `username` is any random username ? like `example.com/makromat` ?

Answer (score 0):

You are putting this in your / location, that means that all your requests not matched before you drop here.  You have to create a location role specific for this entry before the location /

```
location ^/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-/_]+)$ {
    rewrite ^/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-/_]+)$ /admin/index.php?hotelname=$1&do=$2;
}
```